# Multiple Slideshow in one page

Tags: javascript

Could you please help to use multiple slideshow based on the code below. It works fine if only one slideshow is on the page, in other case I have to copy the code multiple times and give different IDs to the elements. Is there any solution to solve this without copy the code?

Here is the code from w3schools:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same code with multiple slideshows you can add parameters to the `showSlides` function

```
   var slideIndex = 1;

showSlides(slideIndex,"mySlides","dots");

function plusSlides(n,nSliders,nDots) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n,nSliders,nDots);
}

function currentSlide(n,nSliders,nDots) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n,nSliders,nDots);
}
function showSlides(n,nSliders,nDots) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName(String(nSliders));
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName(nDots);
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Like this you have to change only in html files the arguments of the function

html:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,'mySlides','dots')">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1,'mySlides','dots')">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1,'mySlides','dots')"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2,'mySlides','dots')"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3,'mySlides','dots')"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately it cant works. Is there anything i missed out ?

Comment: @Quantz98 What is the error?I deleted also 2 extra ,

Comment: @Quantz98 Did you changed the arguments of functions in html also ?

Comment: can u give some examples, I fairly new to Javascript

Comment: onclick="plusSlides(1,"mySlides","dots") ||| onclick="currentSlide(1,"mySlides","dots")"